# SELECT values of each row within groups on a table with composite primary key

Tags: sql, ignite

I'm using Ignite 2.8.1
I have a table `T1(a,b,c)` with both `a` and `b` as primary columns.
I want to know the value of each `b` in each of the group.

Normally this would be fine since the primary key is functionally dependent on the grouped column `c` in this case but Ignite's returning an error saying `b` must be one of `group by`'a columns...which wouldn't be what I want, in fact that'd be the same as not grouping.

Using the available [SELECT](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/select) - can you suggest how to get Ignite to produce both `a` and `b` for each group, or even just `b`. It happily produces `a` as if it is the only column in the primary key.

Comment: I suppose there are multiple different `a` - `b` combinations per each group, how do you imaging both grouping and not grouping?

Comment: @AlexLarionov there isn't, the data within each group is unique. In fact, Ignite is returning  rows if only `a` is selected e.g. `SELECT a, count(c) FROM T1 GROUP BY c` will return `a` but `a` by itself IS NOT unique, the unique combination is `a` AND `b`.

Comment: why can't you just `SELECT a, b, c ...` then?

Comment: Because `SELECT a,b,c,count(c)...GROUP BY c` returns `"__Z0.c" must be in the GROUP BY list`. Maybe I'm not being clear, `COUNT(c) x` is important  so if `x = 10`, I want to know the 10 `a, b` combinations that made up that 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might just want to precalculate counts for each group and then add this information for each `a` & `b` combination:

```
SELECT a, b, c, cnt
FROM T1 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT c, COUNT(c) as cnt 
  FROM T1 
  GROUP BY c
) counts
ON counts.c = c
```

Comment: That's it, thank you - just to be clear. This works because `counts.c` is unique right, so when the join on `T1` happens, it's always being joined with rows that matched that value of `c`?

Comment: Yes. Some RDBMS also support *window functions* that are doing the same but with less code. I'm not sure if Ignite supports them, but it would look like that `SELECT a, b, c, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY c) as count FROM T1`

Comment: Thanks. I familiar with window functions from other SQL systems but Ignite unfortunately doesn't support `OVER(PARTITION...`.